# How to stop Google sheet from auto convert dates to numbers?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

The way that Google sheets handle date values is very confusing to me... The format option of "Automatic" seems to convert dates to numbers often.

Can be reproduced easily as follows:

- open any sheet, in one cell, type down a date such as 2022-07-01
- then select this column, and click Format -> Numbers -> Automatic, 2022-07-01 would change to 44743
- if I instead click Format -> Number -> Date, it would change to 7/1/2022

Based on this, I'm getting the impression that the "Automatic" option of processing dates is to treat dates as numbers by default... Which doesn't make much sense to me. How can I get around this? I want the default behavior to stay as just as dates.

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your question and your tag of `google-sheets-api`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I initially discovered this issue when using Google sheet Java API. When I call append API to write '2022-07-01' with USER_ENTERED option, I hit this issue. Then after some poking around, turns out this happens even when I manual typed...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I initially discovered this issue when using Google sheet Java API.`, I understood that you are using Sheets API with Java. So, I added a tag of `Java`. And, in your question, I think that when you provide your current script for correctly replicating your issue, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: @yagav If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to change the automatic behavior, however, based in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) as a workaround you can use the API to send a batch update to change the cell format to `Date`.

For this you would need to use the API method `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` and include  a UpdateCells request. What you are looking to modify in the request is the `NumberFormatType` parameter and set the value to `DATE` in order to change the format.

References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [NumberFormatType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#numberformattype)